# Help, I May Have a Rootkit

Tags: openvpn, vps, rkhunter

It's been a while since I have been here. I have been very preoccupied with trying to sort out endless problems with my devices getting hacked. I have a bridge set up on my home network. It is a TP-Link 841N, and I had wds enabled, connected as a client on my network. Nmap tells me that port 22 is open, and I have tried to reflash the firmware several times, downloading it through many different proxies, including two openvpn servers, my cellular connection, and the tor network. I also recently had to have my vps provider pgp me a new password because the openvz web panel kept getting hacked. This happened 3 or 4 times, and my provider had to reset the password. So, I scanned my computer for rootkits with both chkroot and rkhunter, and got quite a few warnings. I will post the output here: (Edited for formatting, 1/19/15)

```
     ##Chrkrootkit output:##
        root@linuxpc:~# chkrootkit
        ROOTDIR is `/'
        Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while... The following suspicious files and directories were found:  
        /usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
     /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path /usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.7.0-openjdk amd64.jinfo
        /usr/lib/debug/.build-id

        Searching for Suckit rootkit...     Warning: /sbin/init INFECTED

    Checking `sniffer'...      lo: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets
        wlan0:          PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/wpa_supplicant[1850], /sbin/dhclient[3145])

    Checking `wted'...  1 deletion(s) between Sat Jan 17 21:43:47 2015 and Sat Jan 17 21:48:36 2015
        Checking `chkutmp'...   The tty of the following user process(es) were not found in /var/run/utmp !
        ! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
        ! root         1463 tty7   /usr/bin/X :0 -background none -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-4y3SbT/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt7
        chkutmp: nothing deleted
        Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not infected
        root@linuxpc:~# Searching for Suckit rootkit...         Warning: /sbin/init INFECTED
        Searching: command not found 
        ##------------##
        #Rkhunter Output##
        anon@linuxpc:~$ cat /var/log/rkhunter.log | grep Warning
    [03:36:46]   /usr/sbin/chroot                                [ Warning ]
    [03:36:46] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:47]   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:47] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:48]   /usr/bin/awk                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:36:48] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:48]   /usr/bin/basename                               [ Warning ]
    [03:36:48] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:49]   /usr/bin/curl                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:49] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/curl' exists on the system, but it is not present in the rkhunter.dat file.
    [03:36:49]   /usr/bin/cut                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:36:49] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:49]   /usr/bin/dirname                                [ Warning ]
    [03:36:49] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:49]   /usr/bin/du                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:36:49] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:50]   /usr/bin/env                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:36:50] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:50]   /usr/bin/file                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:50] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:50]   /usr/bin/groups                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:50] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:50]   /usr/bin/head                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:50] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:51]   /usr/bin/id                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:36:51] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:51]   /usr/bin/ldd                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:36:51] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:52]   /usr/bin/logger                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:52] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:52]   /usr/bin/mail                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:52] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/mail' exists on the system, but it is not present in the rkhunter.dat file.
    [03:36:52]   /usr/bin/md5sum                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:52] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:53]   /usr/bin/runcon                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:53] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:53]   /usr/bin/sha1sum                                [ Warning ]
    [03:36:53] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:54]   /usr/bin/sha224sum                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:54] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:54]   /usr/bin/sha256sum                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:54] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:54]   /usr/bin/sha384sum                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:54] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:54]   /usr/bin/sha512sum                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:54] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:54]   /usr/bin/sort                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:54] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:55]   /usr/bin/stat                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:55] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:55]   /usr/bin/tail                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:55] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:55]   /usr/bin/test                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:55] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:56]   /usr/bin/touch                                  [ Warning ]
    [03:36:56] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:56]   /usr/bin/tr                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:36:56] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:56]   /usr/bin/uniq                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:56] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:56]   /usr/bin/users                                  [ Warning ]
    [03:36:56] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:57]   /usr/bin/wc                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:36:57] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:57]   /usr/bin/wget                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:57] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:57]   /usr/bin/whatis                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:57] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:57]   /usr/bin/whereis                                [ Warning ]
    [03:36:57] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:58]   /usr/bin/who                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:36:58] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:58]   /usr/bin/whoami                                 [ Warning ]
    [03:36:58] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:58]   /usr/bin/unhide.rb                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:58] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/unhide.rb' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/unhide.rb: Ruby script, ASCII text
    [03:36:58]   /usr/bin/gawk                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:36:58] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/gawk' exists on the system, but it is not present in the rkhunter.dat file.
    [03:36:58]   /usr/bin/bsd-mailx                              [ Warning ]
    [03:36:58] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/bsd-mailx' exists on the system, but it is not present in the rkhunter.dat file.
    [03:36:59]   /sbin/fsck                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:36:59] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:36:59]   /sbin/ifconfig                                  [ Warning ]
    [03:36:59] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:00]   /sbin/route                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:37:00] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:01]   /bin/bash                                       [ Warning ]
    [03:37:01] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:02]   /bin/cat                                        [ Warning ]
    [03:37:02] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:02]   /bin/chmod                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:02] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:02]   /bin/chown                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:02] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:02]   /bin/cp                                         [ Warning ]
    [03:37:02] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:03]   /bin/date                                       [ Warning ]
    [03:37:03] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:03]   /bin/df                                         [ Warning ]
    [03:37:03] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:03]   /bin/dmesg                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:03] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:03]   /bin/echo                                       [ Warning ]
    [03:37:03] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:04]   /bin/ls                                         [ Warning ]
    [03:37:04] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:05]   /bin/mktemp                                     [ Warning ]
    [03:37:05] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:05]   /bin/more                                       [ Warning ]
    [03:37:05] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:05]   /bin/mount                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:05] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:05]   /bin/mv                                         [ Warning ]
    [03:37:05] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:06]   /bin/netstat                                    [ Warning ]
    [03:37:06] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:06]   /bin/pwd                                        [ Warning ]
    [03:37:06] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:06]   /bin/readlink                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:37:06] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:07]   /bin/touch                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:07] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:07]   /bin/uname                                      [ Warning ]
    [03:37:07] Warning: The file properties have changed:
    [03:37:08]   /usr/bin/mawk                                   [ Warning ]
    [03:37:08] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/mawk' does not exist on the system, but it is present in the rkhunter.dat file.
    [03:46:29]   Checking /dev for suspicious file types         [ Warning ]
    [03:46:29] Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
    [03:46:29]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
    [03:46:29] Warning: Hidden directory found: '/etc/.java: directory '
    [03:46:29] Warning: Hidden directory found: '/dev/.udev: directory '
    [03:46:29] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs' 
## End Output##
```

I don't think it was too long ago that I ran a propupdate, and rkhunter sure is giving me a lot of warnings. The promiscious interface warning was not showing up earlier. Can someone with more expertise please help me decipher these results? I know the suckit rootkit can be a false positive, but Rkhunters is making me nervous, along with all the strange activity I've dealt with on my vps, which was also a tor exit node for a long time. Thanks.

(Update 1/19/15) I took your advice and removed the lines stating nothing was infected, and  upgraded rkhunter. I then ran the new version (1.4.2) and these warnings popped up:

```
[15:48:20]   /usr/local/bin/rkhunter                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:20] Warning: The file '/usr/local/bin/rkhunter' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:20]   /usr/sbin/adduser                               [ Warning ]
[15:48:20] Warning: The command '/usr/sbin/adduser' has been replaced by a script: /usr/sbin/adduser: Perl script, ASCII text executable
[15:48:20]   /usr/sbin/chroot                                [ Warning ]
[15:48:20] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:22]   /usr/sbin/rsyslogd                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:22] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:23]   /usr/bin/awk                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:23] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:23] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/awk' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:23]   /usr/bin/basename                               [ Warning ]
[15:48:23] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:24]   /usr/bin/curl                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:24] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/curl' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:24]   /usr/bin/cut                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:24] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:24]   /usr/bin/dirname                                [ Warning ]
[15:48:24] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:25]   /usr/bin/du                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:25] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:25]   /usr/bin/env                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:25] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:25]   /usr/bin/file                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:25] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:25]   /usr/bin/GET                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:25] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/GET' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:26]   /usr/bin/groups                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:26] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:26]   /usr/bin/head                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:26] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:26]   /usr/bin/id                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:26] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:27]   /usr/bin/ldd                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:27] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:27] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/ldd' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/ldd: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
[15:48:27]   /usr/bin/less                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:27] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/less' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:27]   /usr/bin/locate                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:27] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/locate' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:27]   /usr/bin/logger                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:27] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:28]   /usr/bin/mail                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:28] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/mail' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:28]   /usr/bin/md5sum                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:28] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:29]   /usr/bin/pkill                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:29] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/pkill' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:29]   /usr/bin/runcon                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:29] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:29]   /usr/bin/sha1sum                                [ Warning ]
[15:48:29] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:30]   /usr/bin/sha224sum                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:30] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:30]   /usr/bin/sha256sum                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:30] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:30]   /usr/bin/sha384sum                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:30] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:30]   /usr/bin/sha512sum                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:30] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:31]   /usr/bin/sort                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:31] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:31]   /usr/bin/ssh                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:31] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/ssh' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:31]   /usr/bin/stat                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:31] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:32]   /usr/bin/tail                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:32] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:32]   /usr/bin/telnet                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:32] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/telnet' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:32]   /usr/bin/test                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:32] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:32]   /usr/bin/touch                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:32] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:33] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/touch' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:33]   /usr/bin/tr                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:33] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:33]   /usr/bin/uniq                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:33] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:33]   /usr/bin/users                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:33] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:34]   /usr/bin/w                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:34] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/w' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:34]   /usr/bin/wc                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:34] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:34]   /usr/bin/wget                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:34] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:34]   /usr/bin/whatis                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:34] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:34]   /usr/bin/whereis                                [ Warning ]
[15:48:34] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/which                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/usr/bin/which' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/who                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/whoami                                 [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/gawk                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/gawk' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/lwp-request                            [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/lwp-request' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/lwp-request: Perl script, ASCII text executable
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/bsd-mailx                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:35] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/bsd-mailx' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:35]   /usr/bin/telnet.netkit                          [ Warning ]
[15:48:36] Warning: The file '/usr/bin/telnet.netkit' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:36]   /sbin/depmod                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:36] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/depmod' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:36]   /sbin/fsck                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:36] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:36]   /sbin/ifconfig                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:36] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:37]   /sbin/ifdown                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:37] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/ifdown' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:37]   /sbin/insmod                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:37] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/insmod' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:37]   /sbin/ip                                        [ Warning ]
[15:48:37] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/ip' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:37]   /sbin/lsmod                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:37] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/lsmod' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:38]   /sbin/modinfo                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:38] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/modinfo' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:38]   /sbin/modprobe                                  [ Warning ]
[15:48:38] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/modprobe' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:38]   /sbin/rmmod                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:38] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/sbin/rmmod' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:38]   /sbin/route                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:38] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:39]   /bin/bash                                       [ Warning ]
[15:48:39] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:39]   /bin/cat                                        [ Warning ]
[15:48:39] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:40]   /bin/chmod                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:40] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:40]   /bin/chown                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:40] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:40]   /bin/cp                                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:40] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:40]   /bin/date                                       [ Warning ]
[15:48:40] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:41]   /bin/df                                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:41] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:41]   /bin/dmesg                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:41] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:41]   /bin/echo                                       [ Warning ]
[15:48:41] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:43]   /bin/ls                                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:43] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:43]   /bin/lsmod                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:43] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/bin/lsmod' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:43]   /bin/mktemp                                     [ Warning ]
[15:48:43] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:43]   /bin/more                                       [ Warning ]
[15:48:43] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:43]   /bin/mount                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:43] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:44]   /bin/mv                                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:44] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:44]   /bin/netstat                                    [ Warning ]
[15:48:44] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:44]   /bin/pwd                                        [ Warning ]
[15:48:44] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:45]   /bin/readlink                                   [ Warning ]
[15:48:45] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:45]   /bin/sh                                         [ Warning ]
[15:48:45] Warning: No symbolic link target found for file '/bin/sh' in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[15:48:45]   /bin/touch                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:45] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:46]   /bin/uname                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:46] Warning: The file properties have changed:
[15:48:46]   /bin/which                                      [ Warning ]
[15:48:46] Warning: The command '/bin/which' has been replaced by a script: /bin/which: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
[15:48:46]   /etc/rkhunter.conf                              [ Warning ]
[15:48:46] Warning: The file '/etc/rkhunter.conf' exists on the system, but it is not present in the 'rkhunter.dat' file.
[16:08:55]   Checking /dev for suspicious file types         [ Warning ]
[16:08:55] Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
[16:08:55]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
[16:08:55] Warning: Hidden directory found: /etc/.java: directory 
[16:08:55] Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev: directory 
[16:08:55] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.blkid.tab: ASCII text
[16:08:55] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.blkid.tab.old: ASCII text
[16:08:55] Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs'
```

I can see that some of these warnings are caused by upgrading rkhunter and having old configuration files in /etc, but I am not so sure about the others. Do you still think that things look normal? I sincerely appreciate the help.

Comment: I would remove the parts in that log that clearly state nothing is wrong and leave the lines you think do point to something wrong. I do not see a lot wrong here (btw. did you make sure the rkhunter hashes are up to date). The warnings from 03:36:46 might be due to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use expert tools, also [read the expert manual](http://rkhunter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/rkhunter/rkhunter/files/README).  **You have warnings only, no errors...  ;-)**

Furthermore, rootkits are the most nasty pieces of malware out there and [can hide themselves](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/news/1266502/Black-Hat-2007-Rootkit-hunters-caught-in-cat-and-mouse-game) even from rootkit hunters. [Read the FAQ](http://rkhunter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/rkhunter/rkhunter/files/FAQ) because the correct way of doing this is to boot from a live CD on a CD-R or DVD-R (write once!), mount all your hard-disks read-only, install the software on the RAM disk and *only then* start hunting.

Comment: Good point. Well I tried booting to a live Kali disc and scanning with chkrootkit. I did not get any warnings, however I am not sure if I did it correctly either. I mounted the disc as read only to /media/disc and from /media ran # chkrootkit -R <mountpoint>, and it did not find anything. My /home directory is encrypted though, but I figured that it'd be unlikely for a rootkit to hide in /home... is that a dumb assumption? Also, after removing a router of questionable integrety from my network and rotating all pws and keys, things *seem* back to normal.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: Your question was very helpful to other users too!  2 upvotes!